# I am struggling with setting up the loop for youtube api by using my code each time loop video is loading.I have put only one video in loop

Tags: javascript, youtube, youtube-api, playlist, youtube-iframe-api

Here is my video
http://dynamitechefs.ch/
I have put one video to loop. The video is loading each time. How can I remove video loading?
Here is my code

```
 function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
    player = new YT.Player('player', {
        height: mediaParams['height'],
        width: mediaParams['width'],
        videoId: mediaParams['v'],
        playerVars: {
            controls: 1,
            showinfo: 0 ,
            startAt:1,
            rel:0,
            loop:1,
            playlist : 'BmAL33M0jcI'    
        },
        events: {
            'onReady': onPlayerReady,
            'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
        }
    });
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Based from the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters#loop) of IFrame API Player Parameters, when you play a single video player, a setting of 1 causes the player to play the initial video again and again. In the case of a playlist player (or custom player), the player plays the entire playlist and then starts again at the first video.

> Just take NOTE that currently, the loop parameter only works on the
>   AS3 player when used in conjunction with the playlist parameter. To
>   loop a single video, set the loop parameter value to 1 and set the
>   playlist parameter value to the same video ID already specified in the
>   Player API URL:

```
 https://www.youtube.com/v/VIDEO_ID? > version=3
 &loop=1  
 &playlist=VIDEO_ID
```

For more information, use this [demo](https://developers.google.com/youtube/youtube_player_demo) to know how the different parameters of IFrame API works.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the player.seekTo function to seek to the beginning of the video when the video is close to the end (i.e. 99% complete) to keep the player buffer in memory and prevent a reload.  You can see this example in the code below:

```
var player;
// Callback for when the YouTube iFrame player is ready
function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
  player = new YT.Player('player', {
    // Set Player height and width
    height: '390',
    width: '640',
    // Set the id of the video to be played
    videoId: 'Rykmwn0SMWU',
    // Setup event handelers
    events: {
      'onReady': onPlayerReady,
    }
  });
};

function onPlayerReady() {
var interval = setInterval(function(){
  console.log(player.getCurrentTime() / player.getDuration())
  if (player.getCurrentTime() / player.getDuration()  > .99) {
    player.seekTo(0)
  }
},500);
}
```

Comment: I tried this code.But it still shows the same..I think its not playing from buffer..

Comment: You might have to alter the .99 value depending on the length of the video, or (ideally) you'd have a more sophisticated way to compute the value of the last second of the video to make sure this worked.  Try changing it to a more conservative value ( like .9) and make sure you don't have any errors in your code.